# Python dependency analyzer library

Tags: python, dependency-management

I need a way to find the dependencies for each of my Python package's sub-modules at runtime so I can initialize them in a proper order (see my current [**EDIT:** *former*] solution [here](http://openblox.hg.sourceforge.net/hgweb/openblox/openblox/file/c4ee2c09fe03/src/obengine/depman.py), which doesn't work to well), so at first I used the standard Python module **modulefinder**, but that was way too slow (~1-2 seconds per module).

My next choice was to analyze all the globals of each module, and find from those globals which sub-module each sub-module depends upon. (This is my current solution **EDIT:** I have a better solution now - see my answer). This algorithm is *much* faster than **modulefinder** (it takes <200ms per module), but it only works for relative imports, instead of the fully-qualified import style, which is unacceptable.

So, what I need is either:

- A quicker alternative to **modulefinder**
- An alternative algorithm

**NOTE:** I call my dependency analyzer at the start of each module, like so:

```
# File my_package/module3.py

import my_package.module1 # Some misc. module
import my_package.module2 # Some other misc. module
import my_package.dependency_analyzer

my_package.dependency_analyzer.gendeps()
```

(Just in case it helps you any.)

Thank you!

**EDIT:** I have a solution now - see my answer.

Comment: Why does this have to happen in run time? Do these dependencies change at run time?

Comment: Not normally (there are some exceptions), but I don't want to add an extra dependency map file for each of my modules (which sounds like what you're suggesting), so I decided to analyze each module's dependencies at run-time.

Comment: Or you could implement your packages with some lazy initialization, so that their initialization order doesn't matter.

Comment: If you mean like each module having an **init** method, I already have that. It's just that some modules/sub-packages _must_ be initialized after others. For example, my 3D graphics plugin must be initialized after my configuration module.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I have a solution to my own question :)

Here's what would go into the **dependency_analyzer** module talked about above:

```
import sys
from sys import _getframe as getframe
import atexit

examined_modules = []

def gendeps():
    """Adds the calling module to the initialization queue."""
    # Get the calling module's name, and add it to the intialization queue
    calling_module_name = getframe(1).f_globals['__name__']
    examined_modules.append(calling_module_name)

def init():
    """Initializes all examined modules in the correct order."""

    for module in examined_modules:
        module = sys.modules[module]
        if hasattr(module, 'init'):
            module.init()
        if hasattr(module, 'deinit'):
            # So modules get de-initialized in the correct order,
            # as well
            atexit.register(module.deinit)
```

Now, at the start of each module (*after* all the import statements - this is crucial), a call to **gendeps** is placed. This algorithm works because each time a module is imported, that call to **gendeps** is executed. However, since all of the import statements are placed *before* the call to **gendeps** in your own module, the least-dependent modules are placed in the initialization queue first, and the most-dependent modules are placed in the initialization queue last.